# Trying to achieve DIV jQuery UI slide effect cuts off part of div while transitioning

Tags: jquery

i saw a effect and liked it. here is the js fiddle link of that effect http://jsfiddle.net/lookitstony/EdsP4/

so i try to achieve the same at my end but not working mine.
i have a main div called `MainSlideDIV` and this main div has another two other div those are `"dvUPS_label" & "UPS_rate_time"`. i was trying to achieve the same effect like slide effect cuts off part of div but mine is not working.

here is small js code.

```
function transitionPage() {

            // Hide to left / show from left
            $('.UPS_label').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);

            // Show from right / hide to right
            $('.UPS_rate_time').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('#page1').click(transitionPage);
            //$('#page2').click(transitionPage);

            $('#btnTst').toggle(
                function () {
                    $('.UPS_label').click(transitionPage);
                },
                function () {
                    $('.UPS_rate_time').click(transitionPage);
                }
            );

        });
```

my full code with html,css & js is huge. so i am not posting my full code here rather i will put my js fiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/4289a009/ from here any one can see my full code and guide me what mistake i made for which my code is not working as expected.

so please someone please check the js fiddle link given at top and then you can understand what kind of output i want and then see my js fiddle link at bottom and guide me  why my code is not working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

`<div class="UPS_rate_time">`

to

`<div class="UPS_rate_time nodisplay">`

and you js should be something like this

```
function transitionPage() {
    // Hide to left / show from left
    $('.UPS_label').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);

    // Show from right / hide to right
    $('.UPS_rate_time').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.UPS_label').click(transitionPage);
    $('.UPS_rate_time').click(transitionPage);
    //$('any class or id that you want to use as the toggle element').click(transitionPage);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yx9Lzvty/1/

Comment: i already figured out before your answer but still thanks for your time. thanks